# Uploading limit issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, syntax-error

Hi this my code but when i am uploading files i got always error The message is empty or attachments error. Note: Maximum upload size 10.00 MB

my server config is super fast

PHP Max Post Size   256.00 MB
PHP Maximum Upload Size 50.00 GB
PHP Memory Limit    50.00 GB
MySQL Version   5.5.48-cll
MySQL Packet Size   256.00 MB
PHP 5.5.31

```
public function uploadImage()
    {
        $result = [
            'code' => 0,
            'message' => trans('post.post-image-error')
        ];
        if ($image = \Input::file('image')) {
            $uploadImage = $this->postRepository->uploadImage($image);

            if ($uploadImage) {
                $result['image'] = $uploadImage;
                $result['imageurl'] = \Image::url($uploadImage, 100);
                $result['code'] = 1;
            }
        }

        return json_encode($result);
    }
```

Comment: You need to check your php ini settings. There are specific ones that limit upload size. Depending on your host, you may or may not have access to adjust them. See here, for Drupal, but is a pretty standard configuration method: https://www.drupal.org/node/97193

Comment: Where is the codeIgniter code?

Answer (score 0):

Check in your controller :

```
$config['max_size']= '20000'; // 20mb
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```